# Spring Instantiation exception with java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring

What is wrong with the below bean? Using spring-beans-2.0 I'm getting below exception:

```
<bean id="logger" class="java.lang.String">
      <constructor-arg value="logger"/>
</bean>
```

logger bean ibjecting to :

```
<bean id="loggerType" class="java.lang.String" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg value="logger" />
</bean>
```

loggerbean injecting other bean that is correctly have argument as "java.lang.String".

Exception

```
Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.String]: Illegal arguments for constructor; 
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    
  java.lang.ClassCastException@5083198c
```

Comment: Post the code that is using that "logger".

Comment: The config seems good.

Comment: do you inject this `logger` bean to some other bean ?

Comment: post more of stacktrace and xml snippets where `logger` is referred

Comment: @Joshi: Injecting logger bean to other bean

Comment: post more of stacktrace please

Comment: post complete spring configuration file.

Comment: Why are you creating bean of type `String` class?  Is it needed for any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` class has many one-argument constructors so `Spring` could choose wrong one, hence the exception.

I doubt it happens in newer versions of `Spring`. You said that you use `Spring 2` and [there is a bug related to this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7084). But it seems to be fixed in newer versions.

The [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7084) says that it is fixed in version `3.0.3`.

Comment: i am using spring 2.5.6 version, what version solves.

Comment: @user3457336 And the [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7084) I've posted says that it `Affects Version/s: 2.5.5, 2.5.6`. So it is probably exactly why you get this exception.

Comment: @user3457336 "what version solves" the bug report says that `Fix Version/s: 3.0.3`.

Comment: After Migrating to 3.0.3 ,problem solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are *injecting* another bean then use `ref` attribute instead of `value` attribute.

```
<bean id="loggerType" class="java.lang.String" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="logger" />
</bean>
```

Or use `<ref/>` tag with `bean` as attribute

```
<bean id="loggerType" class="java.lang.String" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="logger"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

For more info have a look at *Spring documentation* [References to other beans (collaborators)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-ref-element)

I suggest to move [latest version of Spring - 4.0.6.RELEASE](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)

Comment: This `loggerType` bean is also `java.lang.String` so he could want to inject the text value.

Comment: As per OP post *logger bean ibjecting to :*

Comment: Ok, I was referring to the code `id="loggerType" class="java.lang.String"`

Comment: tried all the ways but still not working , do i need to change spring version?